# Comparing a double value with a double constant

Tags: java, jvm, double, precision

I know that there were some topics about double comparison with delta which is the proper way to compare double values.

However my question is about comparing a double value with a constant. Is there any possibility that a value 0 (read from an xml for example) will be stored by the JVM with a wrong precision? Is there any possibility that:

```
double constant = 0.0;
double reference = readValueFromDocument();//which is 0

boolean result = constant == reference;
```

`result` will not always be `true`?

In more general manner the question shall sound like: Is JVM storing double constants with a wrong precision during the assignation or it's valid only for calculations?

Comment: 0.0, 0.00 or 0 can be represented exactly as 8 byte double. 0.2 _not_. Your case will happen to be always true. Only if the variable is calculated like `0.1-0.2+0.1` you can expect small deviations. This is valid for _all_ computer languages for floating point. Also double does not hold a precision.

Comment: @JoopEggen i see, my initial thoughts were the same but i wanted to clarify this for myself. Can you post your answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.0, 0.00 or 0 can be represented exactly as 8 byte double. 0.2 not. Your case will happen to be always true. Only if the variable is calculated like 0.1-0.2+0.1 you can expect small deviations. This is valid for all computer languages for floating point. Also double does not hold a precision.

For financial software `BigDecimal`, fixed point with a precision, *scale* often is a better choice. `new BigDecimal("12.00")` gives a precision of 2 decimals after the decimal point.